# Trying to use datepicker with jquery CDN

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the datepicker from the jQuery UI using the CDN provided by jQuery and I am getting these errors in Google Chrome and I would like to know why.

jquery-ui.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) 
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
...
```

Comment: You have to include jQuery before jQuery UI.

Comment: @APAD1: Why not post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @APAD1 stated, jQuery UI requires jQuery.

put

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

before

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```